# Porting from Windows 8 to Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-runtime, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to port an app from Windows 8 to Windows Phone 7 and having a hard time trying to figure out equivalents of these lines

```
var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await localFolder.GetFilesAsync();
```

It gets all the files from `localFolder` and saves it in `fileList`

I can do this on Windows Phone using

```
string[] fileList = appStorage.GetFileNames();
```

Where `appStorage` is an instance of `IsolatedStorageFile`. But if I use the above line of code, I can't use certain functions on the files from the list, like if I want to get the creation date of the file, which I can do in WinRT using `file.DateCreated`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If appStorage is an IsolatedStorageFile type, then use the GetCreationTime method [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getcreationtime.aspx](http://bit.ly/JfZCoU)

Comment: It's not just about time, I want to make a list of files like I did in Win8 using `IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await localFolder.GetFilesAsync();`
:)

Comment: You don't have "files" in Windows Phone 7 the same way you do with desktop versions of Windows.  You don't have a local "folder", just IsolatedStorageFile (and IsolatedStorage--key/value store).  Just as using IsolatedStorageFile in a Windows 8 app is different that using the File System.  Also, all the Local Storage File features you have in Win8 are not in Windows Phone 7